# I need to change the wording on my Login page but cant find it?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, login, magento-community

I need to change the wording on my Login page but cant find it? It has its own top heading. The top choices are Account, Login and Signup. I can find the Signup page but not Account or Login. [www.scimac.com](http://www.scimac.com)
Elizabeth

Answer (score 1):

Check the layout file customer.xml in your theme. 
The Login link should be in this tag:

```
<customer_logged_out>.. </customer_logged_out>
```

Also look in `top.links.phtml` in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should first enable `Template Path Hints` in your `System > Configuration > (Change Store View to Specific Store) > Advanced > Developer` and don't forget to put your IP address in the filter above so that only you are seeing these hints.

When you reload the login page you will see red outlines and boxes around a lot of areas in the page. Look close to where your form is and you should find the file path to the file you need to update.

Depending on which extensions you have installed, you may be looking into one of those files rather than the base/default/custom-theme file paths.

---

^ This all assumes you're using Magento 1 CE. Please update the tags on your post to help others here get specifics about your setup.